# JavaFX program won't run though the code is correct?

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, javafx

So I've been following an oracle tutorial on JavaFX and I copied the code EXACTLY. I even went as far as to copy paste it from the text version into my IDE. I'm 100% sure that the code is correct.

[The first one I followed was this video series.](http://youtu.be/o-iRc9XkgZ0)
[The second tutorial I used to ensure that there were no errors in the code](http://youtu.be/N-Qgz6qHhcg) [and the text version I copied](https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1).

In my frustration I decided to go from my desktop to my laptop to work, so I uploaded the faulty code to my online repository and lo and behold! **It suddenly worked!** Which indicates that I am right about there being no errors in the code. But as soon as I make any changes, it stops working again.

The error messages I receive indicates that it happens inside of the Application I'm extending in my `Start.class` where I have the `main()`.

I'm using NetBeans as my IDE, and my project is a Maven project.

Comment: Can you link the tutorial and provide the stack trace? It's hard to know what might be going wrong without that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be that you need to clean the project when you perform changes to the FX parts. Clean before you run it and it will work fine, provided there actually isn't anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Is that cleaning the project from netbeans? Ot using some other build tool?

Comment: Not sure if you're serious or just want clarification. It's the tool you have when you right-click the project. You can also clean and build, but clean is enough to make it work. I'm not sure what that process would be called in other IDEs.

Comment: In an ant build, or a maven build, there's often an option to do a clean. This is actually likely an issue where Netbeans does not identify all the files that need to be rebuilt that are dependent of the JavaFX changes. Essentially, the incremental build process in Netbeans may be buggy.